# Monodroid wcf first call too slow

Tags: wcf, xamarin.android

I do understand that the first wcf call is usually very slow. And that is the case in my app. I have tried to apply various solutions I have found through out internet with very little progress.

But the thing that puzzles me is the fact that all subsequent wcf calls **even after having exited and reentered the app after few minutes** are very fast. Am I correct in thinking that android somehow keeps some dll or whatever resource related to wcf infrastructure in some memory cache so that **even after reentering the app calls are fast** ? If that is the case, can I use this same technique to keep "wcf resources" ready to fire for my app? (I hope my question is clear :-) Thank you in advance

Comment: try to initiate a connection to the service without wcf (e.g. use http request). if it is also slow then this may be some network issue (or network cache on the device). also you did not specify if you have any special security wcf config

Comment: I do not apply any security
BasicHttpBinding http_binding = new BasicHttpBinding( BasicHttpSecurityMode.None );
I will try calling the service without wcf and see how it goes. Thank for the reply

Comment: try the http request thing. also I'm not an android expert but if there is a way to sniff the network level check if the delay is in that level or in the app

Comment: Hi Yaron. I switched to using wcf rest and made call with http webrequest. I can see and improvement of some seconds (not very much but certainly better than with plain wfc). For now I will continue like that. I would like to advance in my projet and later I will try to improve even better web call speed. Thank you for your help.